# Is it valid to extend a type in the same schema doc as the type definition

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, neo4j-graphql-js

I'm struggling to find docs which are clear about this: Can I extend a type in the same schema doc as I define a type? I keep getting errors like the following:

```sh
Error: Cannot extend type "Healthcheck" because it is not defined.
    at assertValidSDL (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:80:11)
    at Object.buildASTSchema (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:69:34)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:23:28)
    at makeExecutableSchema (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29)
    at makeAugmentedExecutableSchema (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/augment.js:75:49)
    at makeAugmentedSchema (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/index.js:232:53)
    at createSchema (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/server/data/graphql-schema.js:36:17)
    at EventEmitter.constructAPI (/Users/rhys.evans/Projects/or/biz-ops-api/server/routes/graphql.js:19:21)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:211:7)
```

Schema doc:

```
directive @deprecated(
  reason: String = "No longer supported"
) on FIELD_DEFINITION | ENUM_VALUE | ARGUMENT_DEFINITION

type Healthcheck {
  code: String
}

type Check {
  name: String
}

extend type Healthcheck {
  checks: [Check]
}
```

I *guess* it's not allowed, but can anyone point me to where the spec/other docs make this clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, type extensions *only* work within the same document as the type definitions. Most libraries that accept multiple documents or type definitions merge all of them into a single document before using that document to generate the schema.

There's nothing wrong with your type definitions from a specification perspective. What you're seeing is a bug that is [specific to neo4j-graphql-js](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-js/issues/208).

Comment: thanks - I'd been trawling through the package, but it's all transpiled so couldn't follow it particularly well.